# Write tests for an angular REST app

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, mocha.js, chai

I've been clueless so far. Say I have this very simple app module:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.service('searchService',  ['$http', function($http){
    var baseURL="https://someonehost.com/product/search&query=";
    return  {
        search: function(query){
            return  $http.get(baseURL+query);
        }
    };
}]);

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope','searchService',function($scope, searchService) {
  searchService.search($scope.searchWords).success(function(data) {
        $scope.responseData=data;
  });   
}]);
```

It works on the browser. Now I tried to test it using karma, mocha & chai. Say I want to write a test case to test the success path of the request. How should I write that? Here is what I'm trying sofar:

```
describe('',function(){
    var $httpBackend = null;
    var locationService = null;
    var baseURL="https://someonehost.com/product/search&query=";

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('myApp');
        inject(function(_$httpBackend_,_locationService_){
            $httpBackend    =   _$httpBackend_;
            locationService =   _locationService_;
        });
    });

    it('test case 1',function(){
        var searchWord = 'car';
        $httpBackend.when('GET',baseURL+searchWord).respond(200,'');
        $httpBackend.expectGET(baseURL+searchWord);
        searchService.search(searchWord).success(function(data) {
          console.log('data: '+data);
        });
        $httpBackend.flush();
    });

});
```

But it returns no data, which it should, in the console:

```
LOG: 'data: '
Firefox 37.0.0 (Ubuntu): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.033 secs / 0.006 secs)
```

Comment: The error suggests that a call is expected to 'car' not 'https://myhost.com/product/search ... &query=car' which is what is happening. I think the problem is with your test.

Comment: yes I know, but I don't know how to write a proper test case for this case as I have no experience/knowledge about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Angular do not accept $http on external services during unit test. You are suppose to provide mocks to fake data and only test the integrity of your code.

What you are trying to do is not unit-test but integration test, and I had the exact same issue few weeks ago. I found this file which override ngMocks and perform a normal query.

https://gist.github.com/kyro38/3371aaac54bf6583852f

In your Karma/Mocha/WhatEver test configuration you import it after angular (example bellow is for Karma) :

```
// Karma configuration
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: './',

    // frameworks to use
    // some available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'chai'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        './bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        './bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        './src/client/test-helpers/angular-mocks-with-real-backend.js', [...]
```

And then you can run your test as you want. Let me know if any trouble.

### Do not forget making your test asynchronous ;)

https://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

### Be careful with $httpBackend

As describe in documentation :

> Fake HTTP backend implementation suitable for unit testing
>   applications that use the $http service.

Try using $http instead.

```
it('should get nok 8 one single contact', function(done) {
    var promise = $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: baseurl + '/contact/list',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            'Accept': '*/*'
        },
        params: {
            nokid: 8
        }
    });
    promise.then(function(result) {
        expect(result.status).toEqual(200);
    }, function(error) {
        expect(error.status).toEqual(200);
    }).
    finally(done);
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#!

Last tips : In your current test, you give a wrong url to expectGET :

```
var searchWord = 'car';
$httpBackend.expectGET(searchWord);
```

### I would try this

```
it('test case 1',function(done){
    $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: baseURL + 'car',
        ...
    }).then(function (success) {
        console.log('data: ' + success.data);
        done(); // stop test from waiting
    }, function (fail) {
        console.log('data: ' + fail);
        done(); // stop test from waiting
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry but I didn't use Jasmine, I only use mocha & chai.

Comment: I thing this should also work for you. Just import angular-mocks-with-real-backend.js after angular to override ngMocks and then call your code as usual.

Comment: yea now it only shows this: Firefox 37.0.0 (Ubuntu)  test case 1 FAILED
 $httpBackend.expectGET is not a function
 @base/dev/test/main_test.js?1bbe45463e0fe836d98e2591cb89caf32a431057:15:3
 
Firefox 37.0.0 (Ubuntu): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.028 secs / 0 secs)

Comment: OK looks like it help. Be carefull about you test, it need to be asynchronous to not fail straight at launch. Also looks like you are still using $httpBackend ... try using $http. Async test : https://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

Comment: I have updated my answer to feet better with your need. Should help.

Comment: thanks for your helps so far. You are right that I give a wrong url to expectGET. I've just updated my question a bit.

Comment: To me, seem wrong using $httpBackend instead of $http ... but I might be wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74847/discussion-between-sebastienbarbier-and-great-question).