# AngularJS $http testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-http

Is it possible to make use of $http without mocking? The service from which the call is made:

```
// Make the request we are interested in testing
ViewingRepositoryService.getThumbnail(obj, "urn:adsk.wipdata:versionedFile:BQLHHmlCRd-bqnr8rxF2xA?version=1", "medium")
    .then(function (data) { // On success (this is what we are expecting)
        console.log('success');
        expect(data).to.deep.equal(mockData); //Validate the data is correct
        done();
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('error');
        done();
    }
);
```

Is not displaying 'success' or 'error'.

Comment: By only seeing this, Cannot say anything. Post your detailed code here. What is in ViewingRepositoryService ?

Comment: I think your service-function looks odd. I am not that into services either but maybe this [tutorial](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html) helps. And you could look at the networking-transfer with wireshark

Comment: Could you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a look at this post : [Write tests for an angular REST app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539880/write-tests-for-an-angular-rest-app/29540200#29540200)

You need to include angular-mocks-with-real-backend.js in your test file and then use $http as usual.